# How to upload a same file with different size in different folder using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

upload one image and insert 2image with same name and different size and different folder

first folder is user_data and another is mid_image.

my php code is here.

```
function photo_gallery()
    {
        global $obj;

        $image_id1 =$_REQUEST['image_id'];
        if($image_id1 ==0)
        {
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
            {
                    $ext = explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name']);
        $image_type = $ext[count($ext) - 1];

                $img = date('dmYhis').'.'.$image_type;
                $image_full_path = (IMAGE_BASE_URL.'/'.$img);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'user_data/'.$img);
                $get_image_size = getimagesize('user_data/'.$img);
            }

        $s=mysql_query("select image_id from photo_gallery ORDER BY image_id DESC");
        $r=mysql_fetch_array($s);       
        $sql_data_array = array('image_name'=>$img,
                                'image_status'=>$image_status,
                                'image_type'=>$image_type,
                                'image_url'=>$image_full_path,
                                'image_dimensions'=>$get_image_size[0].' x '. $get_image_size[1],
                                'image_created_date'=>'now()');
        $obj->Insert('photo_gallery',$sql_data_array);
        $_SESSION['success']="image inserted successfully";
        header('location:multiple.php');

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want from us? To write YOUR code?

Comment: So what errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes TBI duplicate is possible

Comment: Please check that link.

Comment: I want one image upload in different folder with difference size.

Comment: yes, same is the code there

Comment: No TBI now I want upload image and that image upload in two different folder with different size one original size and second 624x624 but image name is same. and database image name field is different.

Comment: thanks TBI It works fine. I solved that Problem. you saved my time. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the main image in one root folder and call the below function twice with different size. Hope this helps.

```
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $new_height, $new_width, $filename ) 
{
  $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $filename);
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) 
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}" );
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'gif' ) 
  $img = imagecreatefromgif( "{$pathToImages}" );
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'png' ) 
  $img = imagecreatefrompng( "{$pathToImages}" );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) 
  imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$filename}" );
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'gif' ) 
  imagegif( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$filename}" );
  if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'png' ) 
  imagepng( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$filename}" );
}
```

Thanks.